# Equivalent of HttpClient.GetStreamAsync but for writing data in POST?

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

`HttpClient` has a `GetStreamAsync` method that gives a stream which you can use to read.

**I'd like the same, but for writing data to the server**.

`HttpClient.PostAsync` is not suitable for me because it requires the data to be written beforehand.

Comment: Where are you getting the data from? If it's a `FileStream` or `NetworkStream` you can pass that to `StreamContent`. Or you can make your own custom stream.

Comment: It shouldn't matter where I'm getting the data from. I would like to write bytes in an async fashion. Maybe a chunk now, maybe another chunk later. Just like with the Stream retrieved with GetStreamAsync, but for writing.

Comment: Can't you just create your own `HttpContent` subclass that does what you want?

Comment: `HttpClient` works on a "pull" basis, it asks you for the data. So you need to work out a way to block or `await` at that point.

Comment: @Charlieface Is there any work to work on a push basis? Without HttpClient, maybe?

Comment: @EtiennedeMartel No. That would still be based on a pull approach. I'd need push approach.

Comment: Like I said, you could make your own `Stream` or your own `HttpContent`, perhaps using a callback lambda `Task<ReadOnlyMemory<byte>> GetMoreData()` which you then pass back to `HttpClient`

Comment: The edit didn't improve the question. `PostAsync` doesn't `require the data to be written beforehand.`. The HTTP *verb* has nothing to do with how the request content is generated. If you use a StreamContent, the body of the request will be pulled from a stream. If you use a `ByteArrayContent` you can use a byte array. There are other `HttpContent`-derived types

Comment: This sounds very much like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), especially the talk about push-vs-pull which has no meaning in HTTP. Are you looking for a way to send a *continuous stream* of items to the server over a long period? HTTP alone doesn't support this. You can use client or server streaming using Websockets through eg SignalR or you can use a more suitable protocol like gRPC. gRPC supports both client and server streaming out of the box

Comment: Before WebSockets, long polling or Server-Sent Events were used to implement server streaming but these required *very* careful coding to avoid wasting the server's resources. SignalR will fall back to them if WebSockets aren't available

Comment: Flashbacks to this article: https://thomaslevesque.com/2013/11/30/uploading-data-with-httpclient-using-a-push-model/

Comment: What you're looking for _was_ called `PushStreamContent` in .NET Framework 4.x, but it didn't make the cut for .NET Core. It's still an open issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/48386

Comment: This class was a custom and not very scalable (due to the long lived request)  trick to emulate streaming JSON that also required explicit server-side support, so I doubt it will ever be added to .NET Core. There are standardized approaches to do this now.

Comment: Repeating the same or better is possible. After all, `PushStreamContent` didn't really push, it only allowed writing to the output stream in a loop. Essentially, "pulling" the data. One could inherit from [StreamContent](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/StreamContent.cs) and override `SerializeToStream/SerializeToStreamAsync` to write items pushed through a a `ChannelReader<T>` or `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. The *downsides* remain though (eg no error handling).

Answer (score 1):

> `HttpClient.PostAsync` is not suitable for me because it requires the data to be written beforehand.

You are mistaken: The `HttpClient.PostAsync` (and `SendAsync`) methods accepts *any* `HttpContent` subclass: you don't have to use `StringContent` or `ByteArrayContent`: just define your own `HttpContent` subclass and "push"/write to the output `Stream` inside the `SerializeToStreamAsync` method:

```cs
async Task Main()
{
    HttpClient hc = new HttpClient();
    
    WriteRequestBodyOnDemandContent myContent = new WriteRequestBodyOnDemandContent();
    
    using( HttpRequestMessage req = new HttpRequestMessage( HttpMethod.Post, "https://example.com" ) { Content = myContent } )
    using( HttpResponseMessage res = await hc.SendAsync( req ) )
    {
        String responseBody = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        responseBody.Dump();
    }
    
    
}

sealed class WriteRequestBodyOnDemandContent : HttpContent
{
    private static readonly UTF8Encoding _utf8NoBom = new UTF8Encoding( encoderShouldEmitUTF8Identifier: false, throwOnInvalidBytes: true );
    
    protected override async Task SerializeToStreamAsync( Stream stream, TransportContext? context )
    {
        await Task.Delay( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 500 ) ).ConfigureAwait(false);
        
        Byte[] buffer = ArrayPool<Byte>.Shared.Rent( minimumLength: 1024 );
        try
        {
            for( Int32 i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            {
                Int32 w = _utf8NoBom.GetBytes( chars: "Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet\r\n\r\n".AsSpan( start: i ), bytes: buffer );
                
                await stream.WriteAsync( buffer.AsMemory( start: 0, length: w ) ).ConfigureAwait(false);
                
                await Task.Delay( TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds( 500 ) ).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            ArrayPool<Byte>.Shared.Return( buffer );
        }
    }

    protected override Boolean TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = default;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the Fiddler HTTPS proxy showing you the raw POST request body, as sent to `example.com`:

[image]